# rmarkdown::render loop stalls after a few iterations

Tags: r-markdown, render

I am trying to generate a large number of html files using `rmarkdown::render` in a loop, with Parameterized reports.

After generating a number of files, it stalls, and I have to restart RStudio. I can generate each individual file in itself; it is not at the same file it stalls each time when I try running the loop.

There is no error message, making it hard for me to debug.

I have tried the following, none of which helped:

- Closing all other programs; reducing the memory used.
- Adding `knitr::knit_meta(clean = TRUE)` before `render`
- Adding `clean = T` inside `render`
- Calling `render` with `callr::r`
- Including `rm([[data]]); gc()` at the end of the .rmd file that is called by `render`

Any other ideas of how to try and solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Taking [This from R Markdown: The Definitive Guide](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/params-knit.html) Where an example is used to render multiple files. Every file would have a it's own name regarding it's param region and year.

```
render_report = function(region, year) {
  rmarkdown::render(
    "MyDocument.Rmd", params = list(
      region = region,
      year = year
    ),
    output_file = paste0("Report-", region, "-", year, ".html")
  )
}
```

Comment: This is what I am doing. After a number of files this process stalls.

Comment: might want to try updating your 'pandoc', since Pandoc is responsible for rendering to HTML. You don't get any error? Have you done this before? what if you tried doing them all to PDF to see if that works atleast for troubleshooting

Comment: I have the newest version of pandoc (2.1.1) I have done it before where it worked, but never with more than 10 html files, which is where it fails.

Comment: Newest Pandoc is 2.11.4: https://pandoc.org/releases.html
It could indeed come from here at some point.